# Hide excel worksheet via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that has a number of worksheets each one with a colaborator name on it (Windows login username).

I've tried via VBA to loop through all Worksheets to match the actual Windows Logged On username with the matching Worksheet, and after the match is done, only that Worksheet is kept visible (with all the others being hiden).

I've managed to do this partially but i can only do it untill it finds the matching worksheet. For example, if the matching username is the third worksheet (in a total of ten for example) the code stops there. I want it to run through all worksheets and only then hide the non matching Worksheets.

First i have the following module:

```
Sub WorksheetFilter()

Dim Username As String
Dim Worksheetname As String

Worksheetname = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name

Username = Environ("Username")

If Worksheetname <> Username Then
   ActiveSheet.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

Then, i call the previous module on the Workbook_Open() event:

```
Option Explicit
Dim WS As Worksheet

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    WorksheetFilter
Next
End Sub
```

Any hints on how this can be achieved?

Thanks,
Vítor

Comment: Is your code linked to a specific worksheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the code below, and put it in the `Workbook` module under the `Workbook_Open` event.

Just loop through all sheets and compare each one with the `username`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sht As Worksheet


Private Sub Workbook_Open()

For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    If Sht.Name = Environ("Username") Then
        Sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Else
        Sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden

        ' option 2: use very hidden, only able to unhide through code (unable to unhide using right-click)
        'Sht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End If

Next Sht

End Sub
```

Comment: If the point is to hide other sheets from different users I would use `xlSheetVeryHidden` to stop them simply unhiding them.

Comment: @TimWilkinson I'm aware with this option (I am using it a lot) , but complying with the PO request, anyway I've this option as well

Comment: @VitorBarreto not sure why you have shifted the answer? as my code is cleaner and easier to use

Answer (score 1):

Please see below: chopped your code around a bit. You do not need to defien the worksheets name. This is for the module level, you can call it in the workbook open event as per usual

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Username As String
Sub WorksheetFilter()

Username = Environ("Username")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets


    If ws.Name <> Username Then
        ws.Visible = False

    Else
        ws.Visible = True
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Please let me know how this works for you! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)